# can't get quodlibet to work on 13.10

Tags: music

I installed `quodlibet` but I can't get it to work. When I select an ogg file it just fades
to dark and then I have to force quit. Any ideas? Thanks,Bob
Edit-Here's the output:

```
$ quodlibet 

Quod Libet is already running. 
W: Unable to write to /home/Bob/.quodlibet/control. Removing it. 
W: Couldn't connect to a device backend. 
W: No device backend, Media Devices browser disabled. 
Error grabbing key 173, 0xdf8120 
Error grabbing key 171, 0xdf8120 
Error grabbing key 172, 0xdf8120 
Error grabbing key 209, 0xdf8120 
Error grabbing key 174, 0xdf8120 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/quodlibet/qltk/session.py:18: Warning: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised 
  gnome.init(app_id, const.VERSION) 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/quodlibet/qltk/session.py:18: Warning: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised 
  gnome.init(app_id, const.VERSION) 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/quodlibet/qltk/session.py:18: Warning: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised 
  gnome.init(app_id, const.VERSION) 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/quodlibet/qltk/session.py:18: Warning: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised 
  gnome.init(app_id, const.VERSION)
```

Comment: Open terminal Ctrl+Alt+t , run `quodlibet`. See if there any errors. If so, add them to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the PPA: https://quodlibet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/downloads.html#ubuntu-logo-ubuntu

QL in Ubuntu 3.10 is quite outdated